# CSS link hover animation

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I am attempting to replicate the the animation that [Codrops have here](http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeLinkEffects/). (example 11, on the blue background).

I've followed their CSS however I am getting a strange result, the text stacks and doesn't appear correctly on hover. You can see it happening in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abnUE/).

Just for reference here is the HTML:

```html
<div id="content" class="small-12 columns the-posts">
    <article id="post-162" class="post-162 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized row">
        <a href="http://localhost/pondera_v3/uncategorized/test-post-6/" rel="bookmark" title="Test Post 6" class="post-title" data-hover="Test Post 6">Test Post 6</a>
    </article>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.the-posts article a.post-title {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: arial, helvetica;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 29px;
}
.the-posts article a.post-title::before {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 0;
    color: #86a63e;
    content: attr(data-hover);
    -webkit-transition: max-width 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: max-width 0.5s;
    transition: max-width 0.5s;
}

.the-posts article a.post-title:hover::before, .the-posts article a.post-title:focus::before {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

I've played with the `overflow` but the solution is alluding me! Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: Your text cannot fit into an area that has 0 width so the line wraps. It continues to wrap until the area is wide enough for it not to wrap. That's why you are seeing it do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a `max-height` that way the overflow line also is hidden:

```
.the-posts article a.post-title::before {    
  max-height:29px;
}
```

View the demo **http://jsfiddle.net/abnUE/2/**

**EDIT**

Now to fix the problem of your comment. ADD this css instead on the `max height`.

```
.the-posts article a.post-title::before {    
  height:0;
}
```

And in the hover :

```
.the-posts article a.post-title:hover::before, .the-posts article a.post-title:focus::before {
height:100%;
}
```

New Demo **http://jsfiddle.net/abnUE/7/**

Answer (score 0):

Add `height:29px;` inside `.the-posts article a.post-title::before`

http://jsfiddle.net/felipemiosso/abnUE/3/

Answer (score 0):

Same basic answer as both Danko & Felipe, except I used

```
max-height: 1em;
```

and had to add it to both ".the-posts article a.post-title"  & ".the-posts article a.post-title:hover::before, .the-posts article a.post-title:focus::before" because when I stopped hovering it had the same issue as before with the text appearing below as it went away.

EDIT: I see my error, I started by adding to the wrong CSS first.  Adding to just the ".the-posts article a.post-title:hover::before, .the-posts article a.post-title:focus::before" fixed the issue on initial hover but still had an issue when you stopped hovering.  Just adding to ".the-posts article a.post-title" fixed it for both.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your anchor. That's the way the original is doing it.

```
overflow:hidden;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/csh8F/1/